# Swift code application crashes on launch with distribution certificate

Tags: ios, swift, certificate, profile

There is issue in my any swift application(Even there is nothing done in application) as I tried to install the application using distribution certificate and profile it is always crashing but if I am using development certificate and profile then it is working fine.
Also if I am using some other Mac system and use same certificates of distribution then it works well. Moreover Build size from my system is lesser than the build size than any other system build size.

I had tried all the suggestions related to this issues and changing settings or certificates but nothing helped me in this case.

Please suggest if you had faced similar issue or anyone you know.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

With Distribution certificate and profile app will not install from Xcode. You need to use only development certificates and profile for install app from Xcode to device. If you want to test with distribution certificate your app you can use test flight or iTune. Check below link for understanding -

- [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21058295/4803556)
- [apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)
- [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)
- [Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial)

Comment: Sorry for confused description. I am not trying to install and run the application for debug purpose. I knew that development certificate and profile is used for the application to test on device but my issue is that when I share the distribution build or install it on device it crashes immediately. If I use similar code and certificate from other system then build works well.

Comment: I am not understanding with developer cer your app is working ? and with distribution cer working app ?

Comment: Okay.
The problem is when I make swift application build from my system using Development profile then application is installed in device and working well if I use Adhoc profile then application is installed in device but crashes on launch.
If is use any other system with same certificates and profile then it worked well for both Development and Adhoc profile. Hope this made my point clear.

Comment: Have you checked your device UUID registered for your distribution profile?

Comment: If UDID will be the issue then it would not install in the device problem is that it install in device but issue is it does not run on the device if the build is created using my system and with adhoc profile. It works well from other system with same profile, certificate, source code and device.